# Subnet exam preparation for a dummie

Tags: networking, subnet

I am an amateur programmer currently wishing to apply for Master degree in SE after obtaining my Bachelor's in an unrelated field.

There is an entrance exam in my country, and this is one of the example questions.

"Divide the range of 10.128.28.0/23 for the given configuration of subnets with the most economical way"

| Number of hosts | Subnet address | Netmask | Broadcast address | Start Host IP | End Host IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 27 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 60 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15 |  |  |  |  |  |

Now, in my years of "coding" I've never encountered anything like this, so I started searching and learning. In the end, I got something like this.

| Number of hosts | Subnet address | Netmask | Broadcast address | Start Host IP | End Host IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192 | 10.128.28.0 | 255.255.255.000 | 10.128.28.255 | 10.128.28.1 | 10.128.28.254 |
| 7 | 10.128.29.0 | 255.255.255.240 | 10.128.29.15 | 10.128.29.1 | 10.128.29.14 |
| 27 | 10.128.29.32 | 255.255.255.224 | 10.128.29.63 | 10.128.29.33 | 10.128.29.62 |
| 3 | 10.128.29.64 | 255.255.255.248 | 10.128.29.71 | 10.128.29.65 | 10.128.29.70 |
| 60 | 10.128.29.128 | 255.255.255.192 | 10.128.29.191 | 10.128.29.129 | 10.128.29.191 |
| 15 | 10.128.29.192 | 255.255.255.224 | 10.128.29.223 | 10.128.29.193 | 10.128.29.222 |

I understand that this is in no way nice, I just wanted to know if I got the idea correctly.

Also, I think it would be more "economical" if I went from biggest subnet to smallest, ignoring order in the table.

Finally, I'm not sure if it is allowable in the context of this question to use different size for netmasks, but I have no idea how to do it with one. I think, in real life, netmask with variable lengths require deeper configuration.